# Open url based of input

Tags: html

I would like to make some field (For example using Form and Select tags)

```
<form method="GET" action="baseURL">
  <select name="agent_id" required>
    <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
    <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
    <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and I would like after clicking on "Submit" to open url in browser which would be made from baseURL and selected option.
The only problem is that I cannot use javascript. (Let's say that I only can do this in pure HTML)
Is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While, perhaps, not in the specific format you want the URL to be in (it will be `baseURL?agent_id=1`), the code you already have will do that.

If you want the URL to be in a different format (such as `baseURL/1`) then you'll need to involve a programming language (HTML is not a programming language).

You can use any server-side language you like. Specify the URL to a server side program in the `action` attribute, construct the URL you want, then redirect to it.

You could also use client-side JS, but you've rejected that.

Comment: I cannot use any server side language as well.

Comment: There aren't any other options.

Comment: Oh.. well. Now I got it working.. Thanks for showing me what I already had in front of my eyes :D